# How to create a login page that replaces the username and password in a get form?

Tags: php, authentication

I need to know if there's a way to create a login page (this can be a very simple one with just two boxes for the username and the password) that takes the username and password introduced and inserts them in this link:

`http://api.blabla.com/?method=blabla.users.authenticate&username=(<USERNAME GOES HERE>)&password=(<PASSWORD GOES HERE>)`.

So, imagine that I've already created the login page, and I introduce `Gogogogoll21` in the username field, and then `123` the password field.

What I would need the page to do is redirect to this link:

`http://api.blabla.com/?method=blabla.users.authenticate&username=Gogogogoll21&password=123`

As you can see, the only thing that the page did was put the username introduced in the username field and put it after "username=", and it did the exact same with the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick, but consider if passing a password in plain text is a good idea

```
<form method="get" action="http://api.blabla.com/">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="blabla.users.authenticate">
    User: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Pass: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is plain HTML, you don't necessarily need PHP to do this.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Thank you very much.